# Half life is censored after buying german Counter-Strike

Tags: steam, counter-strike, half-life

I had a nice, american version of Half-Life, given to me through Steam. However, now that I installed the [Counter-Strike 1 Anthology](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/41/) (EDIT: In Germany), I have a censored Half-Life, with robots instead of HECU grunts, etc.

Is there a way to get the normal Half-Life back, preferably without uninstalling Counter-Strike et al.?

EDIT: After wiping my entire local content and only installed HL1, it is back to normal. But I do want to have the other games, too.

Comment: Try wiping the local content again, install Counter Strike, then install Half-Life. Since some resources are shared, hopefully by installing Half-Life afterwards will replace the proper resources.

Comment: Good idea, I'm downloading as I post.

Comment: @Thebluefish Sadly, this didn't work. I was greeted by robo-grunts once again ...

Comment: Download cs to a different library location so that it won't use shared resources.

Comment: Hm. There might be a way to separate the installation completely, thus eliminating the shared resources. You could also try this [solution posted by OpT1mUs](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-755102.html)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I'm going to bed now but I'll solve it tomorrow :)

Comment: If all else fails, you can ask Steam Support to remove subscription #41 from your account, and then get the uncensored version. Obviously not ideal because you'd be paying twice, but it's a thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### OK, I did it!

**Step 1:** Uninstall *everything* based on goldsrc, just to be sure (though I think you will only need to remove games using HL1's assets).

**Step 2:** Install just Half Life 1, make sure it works properly, and then copy the whole SteamApps/common/Half-Life folder to a different location.

**Step 3:** Install the other goldsrc games, and you will see that HL1 needs to update, which is when it gets censored (a good way to check is `map c3a1b`, the HECU soldiors/robots are just round the corner).

**Step 4:** Copy you backed up Half-Life folder to SteamApps/common/, and tell it to merge directories and replace files where necessary.

**Step 5:** ???

**Step 6:** Launch the game; Profit!

PS: The game cache files like to mess up while doing this, so check them from the properties menu before copying Half-Life back.

Comment: If you verify HL1's files in Steam, does it re-censor it again?